# How to disable logs for Build namespace Test has build number in server level on Liferay DXP

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-service-builder

How to prevent this from appearing in the logs: `com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.OldServiceComponentException: Build namespace Test has build number 23 which is newer than 3 in server level using XML file.`

Kind Regards,
Kiran.

Answer (score -1):

### Explanation

This is a Service Builder issue.

Each Service Builder module has a `service.xml` in which a `<namespace></namespace>` is defined, in your case `Test`. Every module sharing this namespace has to be deployed with the same build number, which is defined in `src/main/resources/service.properties` and will be increased by one each time you rebuild your module with the Service Builder.

### Resolution

Go through your Service Builder modules and check if all service.properties files of each namespace have the same `build.number`.

Guessing from the log you provided, one module has the build number 23 and the one you're trying to deploy has the build number 3, so **setting all build numbers of the `Test` namespace to 23 should fix the problem**.

### Prevention

To prevent this from happening again, make sure that you only run the service builder from the top directory of your project and not from within a module's directory.

This way the Service Builder will rebuild all of your Service Builder modules and therefore increase all of their build numbers by one, so they stay the same.

Answer (score -1):

@quatax explanation is correct but I would argue with the solution and prevention.

**Prevention:**

- make sure that you use unique namespaces in your service builder modules.
- Be careful when you commit the service.properties file. Don't commit unnecessary changes to it. If more developers are working on the same branch they will have different local environments and the number can get out of sync causing the exception.

**Solution:**

The fix would be as mentioned above to increase the number in the file to satisfy the check.

Alternatively, you can adjust your DB entry that holds the version information. THIS IS ONLY FOR LOCAL DEV DATABASES SCENARIO.

Comment: Yes, different namespaces _could_ be used, but there is no need for that and I would advice against it. Namespaces should of course be meaningful and they _do_ have a purpose. Not only do they make it easy to identify tables of a specific module or company, but they also prevent table name collisions (either with Liferay tables or custom tables of third-party modules). Also, if multiple developers work on the same branch they should - as I suggested - only run the Service Builder from the top directory. Merge conflicts can be handled by always choosing the higher build number.

Comment: it does not really matter what directory you run the service builder from. Say you have just one SB project in your workspace and you have 2 dev working on the project with their respective local envs. Git will have version 23. One of the devs creates some modification in it's local SB he increases to 24. Then he switches to another branch and the code gets reset to 23. He tries to deploy and he gets the above error. If you have more SB project you will just unnecessary rebuild you application and multiply the version problem.

Comment: Every service XML file should have his own namespace but this will still not eliminate the above scenario.